# UWP: How can I reset the default application used when clicking a URI?

Tags: uwp, uri

You know how clicking a URI link in a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app will ask the user what application do they want to open that URI with, then the user selects. How do I reset this application and have it ask me again when I tap on the URI? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking from a general system setting point-of-view or when launching URI from your app?

For the general case, users can set this in the [Settings.Default Apps page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs) under "Choose default apps by file type" or "Choose default apps by protocol". Apps can't control this beyond when an app that supports a file type is newly installed it will ask the user.

From within your app you can pass [LauncherOptions.DisplayApplicationPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions.displayapplicationpicker) to show the open with dialog when the app launches a URI:

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("myuri:foo", options);
```

If the goal is to make sure that your app always launches Uri into specific then you can specify that in the options as well. See [LauncherOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions).[TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions.targetapplicationpackagefamilyname#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName) .[LimitPickerToCurrentAppAndAppUriHandlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions.limitpickertocurrentappandappurihandlers#Windows_System_LauncherOptions_LimitPickerToCurrentAppAndAppUriHandlers), etc.